# XCode - how to stop a CAKeyframeAnimation

Tags: ios, xcode, animation

I have a CAKeyframeAnimation in my App. I want to move an image in a cirlce and that's why I'm using CAKeyframeAnimation. Here is my current code:

```
CAKeyframeAnimation *pathAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation        animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
pathAnimation.calculationMode = kCAAnimationPaced;    
pathAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
pathAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
pathAnimation.duration = 5.0;
pathAnimation.repeatCount = 0;

CGMutablePathRef curvedPath = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathMoveToPoint(curvedPath, NULL, 10, 10);

CGRect rectangle = CGRectMake(69,211,239,243);

CGPathAddEllipseInRect(curvedPath, NULL, rectangle);
pathAnimation.path = curvedPath;
CGPathRelease(curvedPath);

[imgView.layer addAnimation:pathAnimation forKey:@"moveTheObject"];
```

And now I want if the user clicks on the display Animation stops and the image is a the current position where it is.

How can I do this?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Use `[imgView.layer removeAnimationForKey:@"moveTheObject"];` or `[imgView.layer removeAllAnimations];`

Answer (score 0):

Yes but then the ImageView moves back to the position before the animation (storyboard). I want it to stop at current position in the animation.